# Crystal Report VS 2008 - multiple tables report deploy

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am having a problem with deploying a multiple tables report into my IIS server. The page shows : "The report you requested requires further information". However, I have tried to set databaselogon at the server-side but it didn't work. (The report is working fine on VS Debugging Mode)

It is confusing that it happens only to a multiple tables report and it is working fine on a single table report.

I am using VS2008 and CrystalReportViewer version 10.

Comment: [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459882/push-data-from-multiple-tables-in-crystal-report) read the program fully helped me lot

Answer (score 1):

When you get "The report you requested requires further information", are you prompted to log in?  I think that is the header message for DB authentication required.

If so, what you need to understand is the concept that the Crystal Reports runtime runs within the security context of the ASP.NET server.  Your database connections within the Crystal Report are probably set up to use Integrated Authentication, which means the report will authenticate to the DB server using the credentials of the ASP.NET process.

In debug mode, the ASP.NET development server runs as your user account.  Undoubtedly, you have access to the DB.  However when you try to run in production mode, the ASP.NET server (by default) is either running as a local account called ASPNET on the IIS server, or as the NetworkService account, depending on what version of IIS you are running.

If you are running IIS 7.x, you need to either give the IIS server's directory object (NtDomainName\ServerName$) access to the DB, or change the security identity of the application pool associated with your ASP.NET application.

Hopefully this sets you on the right track and if you still need more help please post what version of IIS you are running and more information on the error message you are getting.

---

Response to Comment:

To configure Application Pools, in IIS Manager, select the Site in question, click Basic Settings... and check the Application Pool it is assigned to. Then go into Application Pools, you should see the current Identity of the pool listed.  This is the account the application "runs as".  This account needs to have access to all the files and resources in your web application, including your MySQL DB.

You can edit the Identity settings in the Advanced Settings dialog for the Pool.

Unfortunately I can't give you any advice on MySQL since I have never worked with it.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Could you show to set up the directory object or change the security identity? I am using IIS 7.5 and MySQL as my database.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Yes, It prompts to log in but it didn't allow me to fill in the database name field therefore I couldn't log in manually as well. Could you show to set up the directory object or change the security identity? I am using IIS 7.5 and MySQL as my database.