# Push data from multiple tables in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report named CR1.
Now i want to populate the data from multiple tables into my crystal report CR1.
I am using VS2008 and coding language is C# in ASP.net
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So ... if I understand correctly, you have no idea how to build a Crystal report and you want us to tell you how?

Comment: At one point, I edited the crystal-reports tag to include links to primers on topic, but they were removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **stored procedure** and then use it as a data source of your report. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    DataSet ds;
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds = new DataSet();


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Table1.Col1,Table2.Col2,Table3.Col3 From Table1,Table2,Table3 where Table1.id=Table2.id and Table2.id=Table3.id", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument myReportDocument;
        myReportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

        myReportdocument.Load(@"MyPathToReportFile.rpt");



     myReportdocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(ds);



     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
     CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();



       }
```